# Suppose $(x_n)$ is bounded and for all $e \in E$, $<x_n,e> \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.Does this implies that $<x_n,y> \to 0$ for all $y$ in $H$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm reading a solution in which following result is used.

> Suppose $H$ be a hilbert space and $E$ be a ONB for H.Suppose $(x_n)$ is bounded and $<x_n,e>  \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $e \in E$.Does this implies that $<x_n,y> \to 0$ for all $y$ in $H$ ?

I think it is true but unable to prove .Please help.

Comment: Try to write $y$ in terms of the $e\inE$.

Comment: The correct symbols for an inner product in LaTeX are \langle and \rangle,  not < and >.

Comment: @user60589 But $E$ may be uncountable?

Comment: But $\langle y,e\rangle$ is non-zero for at most countable many $e\in E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V := \langle E\rangle $ be the span of $E $, i.e. the set of **finite** linear combinations of the orthonormal basis. It is easy to see $\langle x_n, v\rangle \to 0$.

Now, let $y \in H $ be arbitrary and $\epsilon >0$. There is $v \in V $ with $\Vert v -y\Vert <\epsilon $, since $V $ is dense because $E $ is an orthonormal basis. Now,
$$
|\langle x_n, y\rangle | \leq |\langle x_n, y-v\rangle| + |\langle x_n, v\rangle | \leq C \|y-v\| + |\langle x_n ,v\rangle| \leq C\epsilon +\epsilon
$$
for $n $ large.

Thus, $\langle x_n, y\rangle \to 0$.

Note that the last part of the proof is the usual argument for showing that weak convergence of a **bounded** sequence on a dense subset implies weak convergence on the whole space.

Answer (score 3):

Let $||x_n||<A$

Take $M$ to be the subspace of finite linear combination of basis elements. Then it is easy to see that $M$ is dense in $H.$ $\langle x_n,e\rangle \rightarrow 0 \forall e\implies \langle x_n,m\rangle \rightarrow 0 \forall m\in M$

Now fix $y\in H$. Take $\epsilon >0$

Choose $m\in M$ such that $||m-y||<\epsilon A^{-1} $

As $\langle  x_n,m\rangle \rightarrow 0  $  thereesists $k>0$ such that $$|\langle x_n,e\rangle |<\epsilon$$ for all $n>k$ 
Now 
$$
|\langle x_n,y \rangle|\leq |\langle x_n,y-m \rangle|+|\langle x_n,m \rangle|\leq ||x_n||||y-m||+\langle x_n,m \rangle|<A \epsilon \frac{1}{A}+\epsilon=2\epsilon $$

for all $n>k$